# Saga vs. Unit of work

Tags: database, domain-driven-design, microservices, architectural-patterns, unit-of-work

What's the relationship between the two?

Both are for atomic operations. Both results need to be either success, or failure with rollback to original state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the saga and unit of work patterns intend to ensure consistency of related operations, but at different levels:

- The [saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) aims at ensuring consistency across independent services and without using a two phase commit.
- The [unit of work pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) aims at ensuring consistency (usually within a system) by making sure that the object states and the database states remain aligned according to a transactional logic (i.e database commit or two phase commit).